# What is the safe way to convert a Vec<T> to a &[T]

Tags: rust

How can I assign to a lifetime to a vector's underlying heap allocation without moving it in memory?

The easiest way I've found to do this is

```
pub fn heap_slice<'a, T:'a>(x: Vec<T>) -> &'a [T] {
    use std::mem::forget;
    use std::slice::from_raw_parts;
    x.shrink_to_fit();
    let ptr = x.ptr();
    let len = x.len();
    forget(x);
    unsafe{ from_raw_parts(ptr,len) };
}
```

But this does call `unsafe` outside of the stdlib, which is generally frowned upon. Is there a safe way?

I see the `into_boxed_slice` is doing roughly exact same thing. But how do I recover the `&[T]` and assign it a lifetime once it is a `Box<[T]>`?

Answer (score 6):

A slice (`&'a [T]`) is supposed to represent a view into some array that is owned by another object (e.g. a `Vec<T>` or a `Box<[T]>`). That's why references have a lifetime parameter and `Vec<T>` and `Box<[T]>` don't.

When a slice is "dropped", no memory is freed, because the slice doesn't own the memory. Therefore, your function causes the vector's storage to be leaked. You can't just "magically assign" a lifetime to a slice and make the compiler insert code to free the heap allocation. Just think, what would happen when you copy the slice?

Rust will automatically coerce a vector or a boxed slice to a slice in contexts where a slice is required (except when generics are involved), so really there's no reason to go against the rules and return a slice when you should be returning a vector or a boxed slice.

Perhaps you're writing a library and you're concerned that returning a vector exposes some implementation detail? Well, think of it this way: if you were writing the library in C, you would use raw pointers, but then you would have to write in the API documentation whether the caller is supposed to call some function (and which one) to clean up the resource or not. In Rust, we encode these instructions by using the proper return type, so that the programmer doesn't have to worry about it.

> Can you at least provide a code example how to borrow a `Box<[T]>`? `as_ref()` or `borrow()` do not allow life time assignment

The shortest way to borrow from a `Box<[T]>` is to write `&x` or `&*x` (where `x` is a `Box<[T]>`). `&x` produces a value of type `&Box<[T]>`, which can be coerced to `&[T]` because `Box` implements the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait.

In order to return a slice with a valid lifetime parameter from a function, you must link it to the lifetime parameter of one of the function's input parameters. If you pass a `Box<[T]>` by value to the function, then there's no lifetime you can link to, as Rust expects the `Box` to be dropped by the end of the function (you can prevent that from happening by calling `mem::forget`, but the compiler cannot reason about that). You could always pass the `Box<[T]>` by reference (i.e. `&Box<[T]>`), but that would just introduce an unnecessary layer of indirection, so your function should just accept `&[T]` instead.

Comment: Okay cool so basically I need to wrap slice and add a drop trait thanks! (I'm trying to work with TLS message packets which all together and be a couple KB once combined, I'd prefer not to re-allocate them thus slices since you can easily slice those up, and borrow their contents easily).

Comment: Can you at least provide a code example how to borrow a `Box<[T]>`? `as_ref()` or `borrow()` do not allow file time assignment